# Jquery #div option:selected problem

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to get this to work and I can't find any mistakes. Here is the select options:

```
    <select id="elecspend">
        <option selected="selected" value="month">Monthly Spend</option>
        <option value="yearly">Yearly Spend</option>
        <option value="quarterly">Quarterly Spend</option>
        <option value="consumption">Yearly Consumption (kWh)</option>
    </select>
<div class="consumptext">Enter your monthly spend in here: </div>   <input style="width:    80px;" type="text">
```

Here is the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#elecspend").change(function() {


    if($("#elecspend option:selected").attr('value') == 'monthly') {
        $(".consumptext").html("Please enter your monthly electricity spend");
    }
});
});
```

Thanks for your help guys.
Sam

Comment: You haven't described the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

There's no value "monthly" in your options.  I think you want "month" and you can use `this.value` to get the value.  Try changing this:

```
if($("#elecspend option:selected").attr('value') == 'monthly')
```

to this:

```
if (this.value == 'month')
```

It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tFvtb/.

Comment: Whats the difference between attr('value') and val(). Oh and thanks for your time.

Comment: `.attr("value")` would probably work fine in this case, but if you're already using jQuery, I think `.val()` is cleaner and there are some cross-browser bug cleanups in the jQuery code for `.val()`.  Probably not a big deal either way.

Comment: I've simplfied it even more to just use `this.value`.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused 'monthly' with 'month'. Change the value of the Month entry to 'monthly' and then use this code:

```
$("#elecspend").change(alterPrompt);

function alterPrompt() {
    var selectedValue = $("#elecspend option:selected").attr('value');
    $(".consumptext").html("Please enter your "+ selectedValue +" electricity spend");
}
alterPrompt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if ($("#elecspend").val() == "month")
```

instead of

```
if($("#elecspend option:selected").attr('value') == 'monthly')
```

See the API documentation for [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Here is a jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/38xzL/).

Answer (score 0):

cant you just use `this.value`?

A tip in the future, you allready have found #elecspend in your change you can just use:

```
$("option:selected", this)
```

witch is a faster option.